# Learning python for Data Analysis - problem with datetime.datetime modules

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas_datareader as pdweb
import datetime

Stock_prices = pdweb.get_data_yahoo(["AAPL", "RIL", "TSLA"], start = datetime.datetime(2012,1,1), end = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1) ["Adj Close"])
```

### Error i'm getting:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 Stock_prices = pdweb.get_data_yahoo(["AAPL", "RIL", "TSLA"], start = datetime.datetime(2012,1,1), end = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1) ["Adj Close"])

TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
Stock_prices = pdweb.get_data_yahoo(["AAPL", "RIL", "TSLA"], start = datetime.datetime(2012,1,1), end = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1))['Adj Close']
```

Or

```
Stock_prices = pdweb.get_data_yahoo(["AAPL", "RIL", "TSLA"], start = datetime.datetime(2012,1,1), end = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1))
print(Stock_prices['Adj Close'])

Symbols           AAPL        TSLA  RIL
Date
2012-01-03   50.857235   28.080000  NaN
2012-01-04   51.130558   27.709999  NaN
2012-01-05   51.698215   27.120001  NaN
2012-01-06   52.238651   26.910000  NaN
2012-01-09   52.155792   27.250000  NaN
...                ...         ...  ...
2017-12-22  169.009430  325.200012  NaN
2017-12-26  164.721680  317.290009  NaN
2017-12-27  164.750641  311.640015  NaN
2017-12-28  165.214188  315.359985  NaN
2017-12-29  163.427597  311.350006  NaN
```

Comment: tried your code but TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Replace `datetime` with `datetime.datetime`

Answer (score 0):

what looks wrong is `end = datetime.datetime(2018,1,1) ["Adj Close"]`. Is there a chance you are missing a coma separator ?

Comment: I gave it a shot and this error happened:       ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument